Convert 1minutes interval data to 5min,15min,30min,1hour interval in oracle sql

I have a table which contains data of 1minute time interval of a stock.

I need to convert the data into 5min,15min,30min,1hour time intervals and group the columns.


File content



date
open




27-09-2024  14:30:00
354.7


27-09-2024  14:31:00
354.75


27-09-2024  14:32:00
355.35


27-09-2024  14:33:00
355.2


27-09-2024  14:34:00
354.95


27-09-2024  14:35:00
354.4


27-09-2024  14:36:00
354.7


27-09-2024  14:37:00
354.5


27-09-2024  14:38:00
354.25


27-09-2024  14:39:00
354.15


27-09-2024  14:40:00
354.4



Expected output as :
In 5min interval 5thminute's frequency data should be displayed
Ex:



date
open




27-09-2024  14:30:00
354.7


27-09-2024  14:35:00
354.4


27-09-2024  14:40:00
354.4



Ex : In 5minutes interval if the time is 14:30 then 14:30 values in 1minute interval should be picked. Same for 14:35,14:40,14:45.... values from 1minute should be picked.
Same in 15min,30min interval data should 15thminute's,30thminutes values to be picked.
I have no idea how to convert time to specific intervals and get its values. Is it possible?
Note:

No need for SUM/AVG function for the values.

Time in a days always will be in between 09:15-15:30 only. Seconds values are always 0. date column contains unique values with date and time.



Please provide the expected output for sample input.

Now you've excluded the close column you aren't really converting intervals, you're just selecting the rows with specific times (or rather, specific minute values). What data type is your date column; and will there always be a row for every minute, or might you have to handle one being missing - e.g. by using the previous value?

I think your description is very vague. What to do if multiple rows having the same minute appear, what to do if rows are "missing", what to do with a row at midnight, to what day (or both) should it count? Should the minute part be always a whole 5 minutes or should it be built from the first row per date? What to do if seconds are not 0?...

Do you need an AVERAGE of the records in the time interval or a SUM or just pick the first one of them, the first one which matches the rounded value or all the ones matching the rounded value? Please specify?

Let's assume you have a record with 27-09-2024 14:30:10. Should it be selected or not?

@WernfriedDomscheit No seconds will always be 0. Only Hours and minutes values are present.

Based on your sample output. It looks like you want to filter rows where the minute part of the date is a whole 5 minutes.
Something like
Select * from records 
where
MOD(extract(minute from date),5) = 0

This takes the minute part of the date,  runs it through the Modulo operation,  and only shows entries where the minute part is some exact multiple of 5.  You can extent this to the other intervals.

If date (not its real name, presumably) is actually data type DATE then it will need to be cast to TIMESTAMP before the extract.

Good point,  or use something like TO_CHAR(date_column,'MI') to extract it.  I'm assuming it's a timestamp as it has a time in there.  not used oraclesql in a while!

In Oracle, a DATE date-type has both date and time components. TIMESTAMP can optionally have fractional seconds and/or a time zone.

You could use CONNECT BY LEVEL to generate the timestamps and then just join them with your dataset, such as:
WITH dat AS
(
  SELECT TO_DATE('27-09-2024 14:30:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS dt, 354.7 AS op FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('27-09-2024 14:31:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 354.75 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('27-09-2024 14:32:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 355.35 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('27-09-2024 14:33:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 355.2  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('27-09-2024 14:34:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 354.95 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('27-09-2024 14:35:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 354.4  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('27-09-2024 14:36:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 354.7  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('27-09-2024 14:37:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 354.5  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('27-09-2024 14:38:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 354.25 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('27-09-2024 14:39:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 354.15 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_DATE('27-09-2024 14:40:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 354.4  FROM dual
)
SELECT dat.dt, dat.op
  FROM dat
       INNER JOIN (SELECT TO_DATE('27-09-2024 14:30:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                          + ( 5 * (LEVEL -1) * (1/24/60) ) AS dt 
                     FROM dual
                     CONNECT BY LEVEL < 20 -- or as many as needed
                   ) ts
       ON dat.dt = ts.dt;

probably not the best solution, but an option none the less.

for 5 mins you can try smth like this
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(date, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS date,
    open
FROM
    table
WHERE
    EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM date) IN (0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55) -- 5 min
ORDER BY
    date;

15 min: WHERE EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM "date") IN (0, 15, 30, 45)
30 min: WHERE EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM "date") IN (0, 30)
1 h: WHERE EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM "date") = 0 but note, this filters the data to only include rows where the minute is 00 if it's ok for you case
